# Zoom in and Zoom out not applying in PDFView android

Tags: java, android

I am building android application which contain pdf and I use this library
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer
I want to zoom pdf when I double click on it on my application
I set minZoom, midZoom and maxZoom in my code but it doesn't zoom
this is my code

```
private int index = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pdf = findViewById(R.id.pdf);
        Load(index);
        pdf.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
            }

            public void onDoubleTab() {
            }

            public void onSwipeRight() {
                if (index > 0) {
                    index--;
                }
                Load(index);
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                if (index < pdf.getPageCount()-1) {
                    index++;
                }
                Load(index);
            }

            public void onSwipeBottom() {
            }
        });
}
        private void Load(int index) {
                pdf.fromAsset("file.pdf")
                        .enableSwipe(false)
                        .swipeHorizontal(true)
                        .autoSpacing(true)
                        .defaultPage(index)
                        .fitEachPage(true)
                        .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH)
                        .enableDoubletap(true)
                        .load();
                pdf.setMinZoom(1);
                pdf.setMidZoom(2);
                pdf.setMaxZoom(3);
            }
```

it swipe right and left well but its not zoom in or out
how can I solve that

Comment: What version of `android-pdf-viewer` are you using?

Comment: implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'

Comment: I tried with `3.2.0-beta.1` & if you use `enableSwipe(true)` & remove `setOnTouchListener`. It works fine for me.